# calculate GCD of two numbers in C

Tags: c, recursion, return

A program to **calculate GCD of two numbers**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int findgcd(int x,int y)
{
 while(x!=y)
 {
  if(x>y)
  {
   return findgcd(x-y,y);
  }
  else
  {
   return findgcd(x,y-x);
  }
 }
 return x;
}

void main()
{
 int n1,n2,gcd;
 clrscr();
 printf("\n GCD Calculator [ Please Enter Positive Integer number. ]\n");
 printf("\nEnter 1st numbers: ");
 scanf("%d",&n1);
 printf("\nEnter 2nd numbers: ");
 scanf("%d",&n2);
 if(n1>0 && n2>0)
 {
  gcd=findgcd(n1,n2);
  printf("\nGCD of %d and %d is: %d ",n1,n2,gcd);
 }
 else
 {
  printf("\n Sorry, Wrong Input.");
 }
 getch();
}
```

is there another way to calculate GCD of two numbers with recursion in C.

OR,without recursion how can i write this program in simple way?

Comment: What makes you think `findgcd()` returns two values?

Comment: return findgcd(x,y-x); is a call made to itself, the same function. This is called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Comment: "*To understand recursion you need to understand recursion ...*"

Comment: You will find your answer after learning some C programming and studying `recursion`.

Comment: Replace the book that told you to use `void main()`; its author doesn't know the language very well. `int main(void)` is correct.

Comment: Although I feel the downvotes are judging hard, what I do not understand are the upvotes ...

Comment: @Matt: It's called recursion, not recursivity.

Comment: @KeithThompson My mistake. French is my motherlanguage :) I edited

Comment: OT: It's either "mother/native tongue" or "native/first language" ... SCR :-) @Matt

Comment: @Matt: No problem. Your English is a lot better than my French.

Comment: plz,help to solve this problem[edited Question]

Answer (score 2):

The return mechanism works quite normally in this program. To understand how the multiple return statements resolve to a single return point from the function, you'll need to learn how `while` and `if...else` work.

I suggest you try to separate the two ideas of

- the execution of a single instance of the function.
- the recursive nature of the function calling itself.

The statement

```
return anyfunc();
```

is a single return point when encountered in the code path. It calls another function and then returns whatever that function returns. Since `if ... else ...` only executes one of the two subordinate statements, only one of the two returns will be invoked. The final one catches the case where the initial condition of the loop was false, and so the loop was never entered.

The recursive issue is a different can of worms, but you need to be clear on the above, or recursion will leave you hopelessly confused. :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit clearer:

```
int findgcd(int x,int y)
{
 if(x!=y)
 {
  if(x>y)
  {
   return findgcd(x-y,y);
  }
  else
  {
   return findgcd(x,y-x);
  }
 }
 return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return findgcd(x, y-x);
```

is the same thing as:

```
int t = findgcd(x, y-x);
return t;
```

I hope that helps you see that it only returns one value.

Comment: But with the while, won't this loop infinitely?

Comment: @Jim I only wanted to address the multiple return value part of the question since that was highlighted. Yes, there are probably other problems with the code.

Comment: I understand, just a comment to clarify.  I thought he was referring to returning multiple things at once, and not multiple returns, but your interpretation makes more sense.  Recursive calls should probably have a single return, in general.

Answer (score 0):

`return findgcd(var1,var2)` is recursive. `findgcd()` keeps calling itself until the conditional statement `while` isn't true anymore-- which isn't actually correct, it should be an `if`. Once it's not true, it returns the inputted parameter `x`. Once `x` is returned the stack unravels until `gcd=findgcd(n1,n2);` is hit.